# Redirect to Referring URL after Login

Tags: wp-redirect

What I'm after is to simply redirect a user to the referring URL after they have logged in. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I've read everything I possibly can, but either the posts I find are 4-5 years old or whatever posted code I try doesn't seem to work.

I'm on a multisite and would prefer something that would be applied to all subsites, but for now, I can settle with something that modifies each site individually.

Here's the latest I've tried which is code that I found somewhere but this continues to redirect the user to their profile on the admin side.

```
function redirect_after_login() {
    $refer=urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    global $redirect_to;
    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
        $redirect_to = $refer;
    }
}
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_after_login');
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Does your site use domain mapping? If so what plugin or code. Also, I'm not sure `$redirect_to` is a global reference.

Comment: Actually this code looks a bit squirrelly. There is no `else` to release the global, nor a proper `return`.

Comment: You never set any `redirect_to` in your function parameters. That is required. Check it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Comment: So is a `return` value

Comment: Yes.. using WPMU DEV's Domain mapping plugin.

Comment: Add that to your question. It is beyond helpful to other users.

Comment: Btw, you are not returning anything...

Answer (score 3):

Your code is completely flawed - not to mention you can't redirect to the HTTP referer after login... because the referer *is* now the login page. Instead, use the [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function ( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to ) {
    if ( ! $requested_redirect_to ) {
        $redirect_to = wp_get_referer();
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Note that we only override `$redirect_to` if `$requested_redirect_to` is "empty", otherwise:

1. It will break the `redirect_to` URL parameter that both WordPress and many plugins use to set specific post-login redirects other than the default (too many times have I seen plugins completely break this feature).
2. If we *always* set it to the referer, we'll end up with the login page itself (as mentioned earlier). This is because  when a user first lands on the login page, WordPress sets a hidden `redirect_to` field with the value of `$redirect_to`. On subsequent page load (i.e. logging in), this becomes the `$requested_redirect_to` value.